# C# generated .XML file not including other file class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-documentation, sandcastle, docfx

I am writing a C# winforms application, and I would like to create documentation for my code with XML comments. However, it seems like I am doing something wrong and can't figure out what is it. Currently, for generating HTML documentation I am using [DocFX](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/) (but i also tried [sandcastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) , but with the same result). When XML File and HTML documentation is created, it seems to only consists of my main `Form1.cs` class(which is interesting because in that particular file I dont have any XML comments). Other `.cs` files(which consist of XML comments) are not included (they were added to the project throughout development via visual studio with right-click on project -> Add -> New item -> C# class). Here is my `docfx.json` :

```
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": [
            "*.cs"
          ],
          "cwd": ".",
          "exclude": [
            "**/obj/**",
            "**/bin/**",
            "_site/**"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dest": "obj/api"
    }
  ],
  "build": {
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "api/**.yml"
        ],
        "cwd": "obj"
      },
      {
        "files": [
          "api/*.md",
          "articles/**.md",
          "toc.yml",
          "*.md"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "obj/**",
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "images/**"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "obj/**",
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "overwrite": [
      {
        "files": [
          "apidoc/**.md"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "obj/**",
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "dest": "_site",
    "template": [
      "default"
    ]
  }
}
```

And also, my files hierarchy looks like this : [image: files hierarchy]

How do I include other files in XML creation as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Could the reason be that the classes for which the documentation is not generated are internal classes? I believe that documentation is generated only for public classes by default.